# Evaluate by contour integration $\int_0^1\frac{dx}{(x^2-x^3)^{1/3}}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Evaluate by contour integration [i am learning complex analysis - calculus of residues]

$$\int_0^1\frac{dx}{(x^2-x^3)^{1/3}}$$

I tried by taking $x^3$ out from the denominator but that didnt work.

Comment: @Diego You can't do it with residues! Those are branch points.

Comment: You can do it with residues, but you'll need to understand the Riemann surface of $f(z)=(z^2-z^3)^{-1/3}$ and compute a residue at infinity.

Comment: Yes, and then equate that to the contour "close" around $[0,1]$ I guess

Comment: It is $\text{B}\left(\dfrac13,\dfrac23\right)=\dfrac{\pi}{\sin\frac{\pi}3}$, but you're asking contour integration and I don't know.

Comment: Substituting $u=\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{x}-1}$, the integral becomes $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{(x^2-x^3)^{1/3}}=3\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{u}{u^3+1}\mathrm{d}u$. Would it be cheating to first make the substitution, then evaluate this easier integral by contour integration?

Comment: As an aside, see [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) and Euler's [reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) for the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Properties).

Answer (score 4):

Use a dogbone contour with a single branch around [0,1].

Consider $$f(z)=\frac{1}{z^{2/3}(1-z)^{1/3}}$$ and use the branches

$\displaystyle -\pi\leq arg(z)<\pi, \;\  0\leq arg(1-z)< 2\pi$

Arg above the cut:  $arg(z)=0, \;\ arg(1-z)=2\pi$

Arg below the cut:  $arg(z)=0, \;\ arg(1-z)=0$

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{|z|^{2/3}e^{2i\cdot arg(z)/3}|1-z|^{1/3}e^{i\cdot arg(1-z)/3}}$$

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x^{2/3}e^{2i (0)/3}(1-x)^{1/3}e^{i(2\pi )/3}}dx-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x^{2/3}e^{2i(0)/3}(1-x)^{1/2}e^{i(0)/3}}dx=2\pi i Res(f,\infty)$$

the residue at infinity is $e^{2\pi i /3}$,  (I have to admit I just done this with Mathematica to save some time, or one may use the Laurent expansion) so:

$$(e^{-2\pi i/3}-1)\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x^{2/3}(1-x)^{1/3}}dx=2\pi i e^{2\pi i/3}$$

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x^{2/3}(1-x)^{1/3}}dx=\frac{2\pi i e^{2\pi i/3}}{e^{-2\pi i/3}-1}=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{3}}$$

EDIT:

To find the residue at infinity, one can multiply by $-1/x^{2}$ and let $x\to 1/x$ to obtain the series expansion about 0:

$\displaystyle \frac{-1}{x^{2}}\cdot \frac{1}{\frac{1}{x^{2/3}}(1-\frac{1}{x})^{1/3}}=\frac{e^{2\pi i/3}}{x}+\frac{e^{2\pi i/3}}{3}+\frac{2e^{2\pi i/3}}{9}x+\cdot\cdot\cdot $

The coefficient of the 1/x term is the residue.

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
\begin{align}
\color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{1}{\dd x \over \pars{x^{2} - x^{3}}^{1/3}}}&
=\int_{\infty}^{1}{-\dd x/x^{2} \over \pars{1/x^{2} - 1/x^{3}}^{1/3}}
=\int_{1}^{\infty}{\dd x \over x\pars{x - 1}^{1/3}}
=\color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{-1/3}\,\dd x \over x + 1}}
\end{align}
Use the following contour with
$\ds{z^{-1/3} = \verts{z}^{-1/3}\expo{-\ic\phi\pars{z}/3}\,,\qquad
0 < \phi\pars{z} < 2\pi}$:
[image]

> \begin{align}
> \color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{-1/3}\,\dd x \over x + 1}}
> &=2\pi\ic\expo{-\pi\ic/3}
> -\int_{\infty}^{0}{x^{-1/3}\expo{-2\pi\ic/3}\,\dd x \over x + 1}
> =2\pi\ic\expo{-\pi\ic/3}
> +\expo{-2\pi\ic/3}\color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{-1/3}\,\dd x \over x + 1}}
> \end{align}

\begin{align}
\color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{-1/3}\,\dd x \over x + 1}}&=
2\pi\ic\,{\expo{-\pi\ic/3} \over 1 - \expo{-2\pi\ic/3}}
=
2\pi\ic\,{1 \over \expo{\pi\ic/3} - \expo{-\pi\ic/3}}
={2\pi\ic \over 2\ic\sin\pars{\pi/3}}={\pi \over \sin\pars{\pi/3}}
\\[3mm]&={\pi \over \root{3}/2} = {2\root{3} \over 3}\,\pi
\end{align}

> $$
> \color{#66f}{\large\int_{0}^{1}{\dd x \over \pars{x^{2} - x^{3}}^{1/3}}
> ={2\root{3} \over 3}\,\pi} \approx 3.6276
> $$